# Almost identical methods to print an array, differing only by argument type

Tags: c#, overloading

It's very basic. I'm learning C# and I want a method to print an array in a readable format. My array could be integers, doubles, or strings. I have implemented method overloading.

From the fact that my method behaves the same way regardless of the input type is, I end up copying and pasting the same code and change the argument type.

My question is, is repeating the code the one and only way to do it? I'm talking about convention here. What do professionals do with this kind of problem?

```
        static string PrintArray(int[] inputArray)
        {
            string s = String.Join(", ", inputArray);
            return s;
        }

        static string PrintArray(string[] inputArray)
        {
            string s = String.Join(", ", inputArray);
            return s;
        }

        static string PrintArray(double[] inputArray)
        {
            string s = String.Join(", ", inputArray);
            return s;
        }
```

Comment: How many times do you call these functions, and what are you passing to them? The answer will influence whether these functions are justifiable.

Comment: Well, I was expecting a general answer rather than focusing on this function itself. But I showed this code just to elaborate what I encountered during the process of learning.

Comment: If you call these functions once, the review answer will be "delete everything". If you call these functions dozens of times the answer will change, and may or may not recommend extension methods or generics depending on use. There is no general answer. I am voting closure until you add contextual usage.

Comment: I wanted to understand if we encounter a situation that we have a function that the code inside it is exactly the same but the input data type can vary, do we need to repeat the code just as in this example, or is there any other sophisticated way to do it, thanks.

Comment: Around here that's called a hypothetical, and those are off-topic. I would be thrilled to review code from a real project.

Comment: Sure, if we were to call that following tutorials a project, that’s the one I have.

Comment: Go for it! Please include enough code for it to be executable by your reviewers.

Comment: Shouldn't this solve your problem: `static string PrintArray<T>(T[] inputArray) => String.Join(", ", inputArray)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I end up copying and pasting the same code and change the argument type

This is precisely why generic types have been invented. At their very core, generic type parameters are "type variables" where the caller (i.e. not the generic class/method itself) can decide what the specific type is.

That `String.Join` method you are using **already does this**, [as per the MSDN documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0#system-string-join-1(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))). This is why you're able to pass in any kind of arrays.

You can rework your methods to be a single generic method as well:

```
static string PrintArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputArray)
{
    string s = String.Join(", ", inputArray);
    return s;
}
```

*Note that I've opted to use `IEnumerable<T>` because it allows for many types of collections (not just `T[]`) to be used. This is generally advisable when the code you're writing is not bound to a specific collection type.*

And then you can use this method as you see fit:

```
PrintArray<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
PrintArray<char>(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
PrintArray<string>(new string[] { "abc", "def" });
PrintArray<Person>(new Person[] { new Person("John", "Smith"), new Person("Tom", "Jones") });
```

In cases where the generic type can be inferred from the parameters you pass into the method, the compiler no longer requires you to explicitly set the generic type. The above code can be reduced to:

```
PrintArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
PrintArray(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
PrintArray(new string[] { "abc", "def" });
PrintArray(new Person[] { new Person("John", "Smith"), new Person("Tom", "Jones") });
```

This is precisely why you didn't need to specify the generic type when calling `String.Join`, even though it is in fact a generic method.

---

*For your particular example, your method is really just a useless wrapper around the existing `String.Join` method. In this case, there is little purpose to having this additional method. Your method can be safely removed from the codebase; unless you intend to expand its logic in any way that `String.Join` does not already provide out of the box.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is the kind of the answer I was looking for. because I've never had experienced in the production. just wanted to understand how it should be done properly. and your mention in the last section also makes the point as well!

Comment: @tmo: Glad to be of help. To be quite honest, while I do agree that this question narrowly clears the bar, future questions of a similar scope would be more suited to StackOverflow or SoftwareEngineering.SE, where they won't face closure for being light on reviewable content.

Comment: IMHO `inputArray` is a bad name for an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you would define it as an array and add the `params` prefix then all of your usage samples could be shortened, like `PrintArray(1, 2, 3);`.